# Php print single id issue

Tags: php, mysql

So here's what I want.. When user clicks on some link e.g. http://www.keevik.com/vicevi.php?id=24 that script prints out only that single id.

Here's my code

```
    /* Get data. */
$sql = "SELECT * FROM $tbl_name ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT $start, $limit";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
    echo "<a href ='vicevi.php?id=".$row['id']."'>".$row['id']."</a>";
    echo "<br>";
    echo nl2br($row["VicText"]);
    echo "<hr>";
    }
```

So, when I click on some link it doesn't do what I actually want :S

Comment: Add a where clause `WHERE id=$id` and get it from $_GET['id'];

Comment: ... and escape it properly ;-)

Comment: this is the code of the page where you display the list. What's in the page where you display an item detail ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM $tbl_name ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT $start, $limit";
if(isset($_GET['id']))
{
    $id=intval($_GET['id']);
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE id=$id";
}
$result = mysql_query($sql);
if(!$result)
{
    echo 'no data found!';
}
else
{
    // etc..
}
```

Comment: lookup `mysql_real_escape_string()` but I suggest moving to mysqli